# DataSource on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, datasource

I come up with this thread, because I would like to know what is the best method to implement a datasource class on iOS, when you have to access it from many classes.
Is it ok to be a singleton class? Or is there any better method?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think that's a bad idea at all. Implement the singleton as Apple suggest.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW31 (search "Creating a Singleton Instance" in the page)

Comment: I know how to implementa a singleton class. I want to know that it is ok for a DataSource class or there are far better methods.